# Embedding formalism for 3-points correlators with spin index

Tags: quantum-spin, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

I am studying embedding formalism in order to write correlators more naturally, and came across some questions I cannot find an answer to.

To my understanding, the embedding formalism consists of finding a Lorentz-invariant expression, in an higher dimension space. For a general $d+2$ dimensional tensor field with $l$ spin indices, $\Phi_{M_1...M_l}(X)$, there is a set of rules that the must be met:

- $X^2 = 0$;
- This tensor has to be traceless and possess the same index symmetry as the $d$ dimensional tensor field;
- Must be transverse;
- Must be homogeneous of degree $-\Delta$ in $X$.

From these conditions and the condition that

$$X \cdot \frac{\partial X}{\partial x^c} = 0,$$

I made an attempt to write some correlators for 3 points, with spins 0, 1 and 2.

**Spin 0**

Up to a constant,

\begin{split}
\langle \mathcal{O_1}(X_1)\mathcal{O_2}(X_2)\mathcal{O_3}(X_3)\rangle &=  \left(X_1 \cdot X_2\right)^\alpha\left(X_1 \cdot X_3\right)^\beta\left(X_2 \cdot X_3\right)^\sigma
\end{split}

and $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\sigma$ can be fixed by homogeneity. This is what is usually written. However, why can't we have, for example:

- Sums of pairs of $X_i \cdot X_j$ on the numerator, as well as on the denominator?

**Spin 1**

\begin{split}
\langle \mathcal{O_1}(X_1)\mathcal{O_2}(X_2)\mathcal{V}^{A_1}(X_3)\rangle &=  \frac{ aX_{1}^{A_1}X_2 \cdot X_3 +bX_{2}^{A_1}X_1 \cdot X_3 +cX_{3}^{A_1}X_2 \cdot X_3 }{\left(X_1 \cdot X_2\right)^\alpha\left(X_1 \cdot X_3\right)^\beta\left(X_2 \cdot X_3\right)^\sigma}.
\end{split}

Again, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\sigma$ can be fixed by homogeneity and the rest either by projection or by transversality. Regarding this case:

- Why can't we multiply each term on the numerator by, say, the rest of the dot products (i.e., for the first term something like $X_1\cdot X_2 \,X_1\cdot X_3$)?
- Why aren't there terms without $X_i \cdot X_j$ on the numerator?

Comment: Because of the last condition. A sum of pairs like $(X_1 \cdot X_2 + X_1 \cdot X_3)^\alpha$ does not transform homogeneously under scaling $X_2$ or $X_3$.

Comment: For the last part, just consider the $a X_1^{A_1}$ term. All of the operations you mention are related by shifting $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\sigma$. So you can always write the $a X_1^{A_1}$ term as in the ansatz above. Then the $b X_2^{A_2}$ and $c X_3^{A_3}$ terms need to have the same weight so there is no freedom left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPs two 3-point correlators are worked out in full detail in Ref. 1. The main restriction comes from maintaining scaling homogeneity of the primary fields, cf. above comments by Connor Behan.

References:

1. S. Rychkov, *EPFL Lectures on Conformal Field Theory in D>= 3 Dimensions,* [arXiv:1601.05000](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05000); Subsections 2.2.2 + 2.3.5.